# Хочу удалить файлы из кеша, выскакивает ошибка

Tags: git

```
git rm --cached ios/build/*
```

> **fatal**: not removing 'ios/build/Build' recursively without **-r**

Подскажите что это?

Comment: Попробуйте `git rm -r --cached ios/build/*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

судя по сообщению, одно из имён, подпадающих под маску — `ios/build/Build` — это каталог, а не файл.

следовательно, надо добавить опцию `-r` (действовать рекурсивно для каталогов):

```
$ git rm -r ...
```